# RakeでC言語をビルドする際、並行コンパイルを行う方法

Tags: ruby, c, rake

#### 前提・実現したいこと

Rakeを用いて、C言語のビルドシステムを構築しています。

複数ファイルをコンパイルする際、CPUの複数のコアを使用して並行でコンパイルできるようにしたいのですが、どのようにRakeファイルを書けばいいのか、アドバイスをいただけないでしょうか？

makeでいう、`make -j` をRakeで実現したいです。

制約として、新たにGemをインストールしない方法が好ましいです。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

Rakeで複数ファイルのコンパイルを同時並行で行う記述方法が分かりません。

#### 該当のソースコード

分かりやすいように、単純化したRakeファイルを記載します。

```
CC = "gcc"

task :default => "hello"

file "hello" => ["hello.o", "message.o"] do
  sh "#{CC} -o hello hello.o message.o"
end

file "hello.o" => "hello.c" do　※1
  sh "#{CC} -c hello.c"
end

file "message.o" => "message.c" do　※2
  sh "#{CC} -c message.c"
end
```

[http://www2s.biglobe.ne.jp/~idesaku/sss/tech/rake/](http://www2s.biglobe.ne.jp/%7Eidesaku/sss/tech/rake/) 抜粋

※1、※2のファイルタスクを同時並行で実行し、並行コンパイルを実現したいです。

#### 試したこと

単純なRakeタスクならば、以下のページに記載のように multitask を用いることで並行してタスクが実行できるのですが、ファイルタスクの場合、どのように記載していいかが分かりません。

http://nilquebe.blogspot.com/2014/06/rake-part-7-multitask.html

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

ruby 2.6.4p104 (2019-08-28 revision 67798) [i386-cygwin]

Comment: pwrake https://github.com/masa16/pwrake

Comment: [英語版](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66167021) や [teratail](https://teratail.com/questions/322028) でも同様の投稿をされていて、一応は回答も付いているように見えます。 解決した/しないに関わらず、別の場所でも質問していることを予め質問中で伝えておいたほうが、やり取りもスムーズになると思います。(ほぼ同じ内容の回答が付いてしまう可能性も)

Comment: pwrakeですが、cygwin上では動かなかったです。
他にも、drakeというものもあるようですね。
http://quix.github.io/rake/

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。
気を付けるようにします

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rake -m
```

というのも、あるようですが、ご希望には沿わないですか？
並列化、ビルド時間の短縮には、ccache,distccなどもありますね。
頑張ってください。

Comment: rake -m
で全タスクをマルチタスクとみなしてくれることが分かりました。

並行で実行されると困るタスクのみ、個別にタスクを定義しました。

rake -m -j 8
のように指定することで、ビルド時間が短縮されることを確認できました。

Answer (score 1):

Rake の `-m` (`--multitask`) オプションを使用すると、すべてのタスクを `multitask` として扱うので並行コンパイルできると思います。

Comment: 助言いただいた通り、
rake -m
で全タスクをマルチタスクとみなしてくれることが分かりました。

並行で実行されると困るタスクのみ、個別にタスクを定義しました。

rake -m -j 8
のように指定することで、ビルド時間が短縮されることを確認できました。